# How to handle error while checking out a github a pull request?

Tags: git, github

I have checked out a pull request from github using the commands

```
git clone <repo>
cd <repo>
gh pr checkout 19
```

with the [github command line tool](https://github.com/cli/cli). I examined the pull request (which created some completely irrelevant changes). Someone else made a change to that PR. In order to checkout that updates pull request I tried

```
git pull
gh pr checkout 19
```

but I got errors like

```
Switched to branch 'branch'
Your branch and 'origin/branch' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
exit status 128
```

or

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in folder/some_file.py
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

How to solve this issue?

Note: Any changes made are completely irrelevant!

Comment: did you really clone the repo or re-used one you already had and just pulled?

Comment: I think I did a new clone.

Comment: Accoding to your answer you did not, since you had to first delete the old repository. Most likely, you had commits in your local clone, never pushed them, never fetched them, pull, got rejected due to diverging history. Then, deleted local repository, clone a new one, pulled the pr, everything was OK. Also, you did pulled from that branch like "yesterday" (as in the mithological place of the past), then someone `git push -f` to remote destroying the one commit you pulled and pushed the new divergent one.

Answer (score 0):

A marginally better answer than [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62593718/119527) would be to delete the *branch* rather than the entire repository:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D the-pr-branch-name
gh pr checkout 123
```

Answer (score -4):

Answer:

```
cd ..
rm -rf <repo>
git clone <repo>
cd <repo>
gh pr checkout 19
```

You delete your entire repository, clone it fresh, and checkout the pull rwequest again.

Comment: very poor quality answer. You tried re-using the local repo. There, you committed stuff without fetching from remote, where somebody else pushed commit on the same branch. In the end, your branch and the remote had diverged. Your solution is to get rid of the local repo

Comment: Exactly! I do not care what has changed on the local repo. I just want it to be at the same state as what is in github!